# Disable "Blogroll" or "WordPress Dashboard News" section in WordPress v.4.1?

Tags: dashboard, blogroll

Is there a way to disable *Blogroll* or *WordPress Dashboard News* section in WordPress v.4.1?

**EDIT:**
Actually by saying disable, i mean completely remove and not just hide.
I apologize for my the late response.

Comment: Do you mean, disable it from the dashboard?

Comment: @gdaniel I have updated my question. I mean completely remove and not just hide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to remove metaboxes from the dashboard page you can add this to functions.php

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets () {

  remove_meta_box('dashboard_quick_press','dashboard','side'); //Quick Press widget
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_drafts','dashboard','side'); //Recent Drafts
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_primary','dashboard','side'); //WordPress.com Blog
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_secondary','dashboard','side'); //Other WordPress News
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_incoming_links','dashboard','normal'); //Incoming Links
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_plugins','dashboard','normal'); //Plugins
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_right_now','dashboard', 'normal'); //Right Now
  remove_meta_box('rg_forms_dashboard','dashboard','normal'); //Gravity Forms
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_comments','dashboard','normal'); //Recent Comments
  remove_meta_box('icl_dashboard_widget','dashboard','normal'); //Multi Language Plugin
  remove_meta_box('dashboard_activity','dashboard', 'normal'); //Activity
  remove_action('welcome_panel','wp_welcome_panel');

}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

Just comment out the ones you want to keep. The first value passed is the metabox ID, so you could also remove other metaboxes that are added by plugins. Just inspect the metabox with your browser and grab the metabox ID.

Comment: Where did you get the code from? Who's work is it?

Comment: I honestly dont know. I have been using this for years. I udually credit when i know.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide them using the screen options or add this code to your child themes functions file:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');

function remove_dashboard_widgets () {

      remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side' );      
      remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_secondary', 'dashboard', 'side' );      


}
```

Source: [`wp_dashboard_setup`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_dashboard_setup#To_Remove_a_Dashboard_Widget)

Comment: using the screen options is "the answer" unless you want to disable something across all/some users

Answer (score 0):

The 'WordPress News' widget is dashboard_primary and (likely for reasons buried somewhere deep in core) sometimes it reappears when using

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

to remove widgets... often can instead use

```
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

so, if having issues with

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets () {
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_primary','dashboard','side');
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

...instead try like this

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets () {
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_primary','dashboard','side');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

and, fwiw, for a network dashboard try using

```
function remove_network_dashboard_widgets() {
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_primary', 'dashboard-network', 'side');
}
add_action( 'wp_network_dashboard_setup', 'remove_network_dashboard_widgets' );
```